# Who needs to get PayPal API credentials and who needs to get a PayPal AppID

Tags: paypal, single-page-application, paypal-adaptive-payments

My company develops something like an online shop system. We serve our software as a multi-tenant SaaS solution to our customers. Our customers are merchants. Our claim was to integrate PayPal as seamless as possible into our software. Our software is an AngularJS (SPA, single page application) application so one requirement for the PayPal integration was not to navigate away from our application. We decided to use "Embedded Payment Flow Using Adaptive Payments". Now we are not sure who has to provide which credentials.

- Each of our customers (merchants) has to provide its own API credentials. Right?
- The AppID is only required once. WE have to get only one AppID no matter how many customers (merchants) are using our software. Right?

Therefore every adaptive payments API call uses the API credentials from the customer + our AppID?!

Greetings from Germany,

Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be a platform that provide service to merchant and customers. PayPal will use your account's API credential and app id.
Refe to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/?mark=API%20caller

Your website will act as a API caller.

Comment: That's amazing. We must over read that part of the documentation! So if we are using PayPal Adaptive Payments API we have to use OUR API credentials and OUR AppID and our customers (which are merchants) just have to set the e-mail address of their PayPal business account in the admin frontend of our application?

Comment: Yes, use your API credential and your APPID. your merchants need to provide PayPal account email address.